# Moving away from academia? How to get contacts and create your opportunity

Tags: job-search, industry, recruiting

I have always worked with academia and have recently started thinking about leaving it.

**Background**
I have done a PhD and after that a post-doc, and am now about 2 years after my postdoc working as senior researcher in a permanent staff position. This amounts to about 4 years after PhD.

However, I feel that I'd enjoy going to industry as it would not be working just to get papers. My hope is that I could work with others with a more applied focus (in the sense of working on a product for instance). I have currently no issues in my job, and still find it exciting as I'm learning a lot. But in the long term, I feel that the lack of career progression and that working only to get papers will be motivation to move away from academia.

I'm aware that I currently have a good number of good publications and desirable skillset - for the time being, at least. I have no time constraints that would make me have to rush this.

**The problem**
I have identified a few companies that I see as good targets for me, but don't know who to approach to create an opportunity. I have perhaps 1 contact in 3 of the companies, but even this is more of an acquaintance in a low level position. I'm wondering what are your suggestions in how to get contacts or get the first step in moving. I feel that in academia this is very straightforward, in the sense that you can just email people and introduce yourself (this worked well before). These companies occasionally have openings, but I feel that creating my own opportunity would be more helpful to find a better fit.